# Android device camera crash issue in Android version > 6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

In some of the android devices which have android version > 6.0, when i access the camera, device camera gets opened and when i capture and accept the pic, camera is crashing(loads the camera again) and i have camera access permission . what can be done? any idea?

Comment: Its because of run time permission.

Comment: Add     android:hardwareAccelerated="true"    and  
   android:largeHeap="true"   to manifest file of your application, inside application block , it might help you out,,

Comment: Hi, you never mentioned your Unity version. Just update Unity to be latest version which supports the new permission type.

Comment: i have Unity 5.5.3 and it is supporting permissions. Even if the permission is granted, i am getting the crash when i click some picture and confirm it to load to my application

Comment: Error logs with AndroiNative tag: AndroidNativeProxy onStop AndroidNativeProxy onStart AndroidNativeProxy::onStart 0 AndroidNativeProxy::onActivityResult 2930 -1 RESULT_IMAGE_CAPTURE captured RESULT_IMAGE_CAPTURE captured. ActivityResult RESULT_OK AndroidNativeProxy::onActivityResult Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference AndroidNativeProxy onStop

Answer (score 1):

you need to ask **[run time permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)** because **Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.**

> **ask for run time permission for camera using below code**

```
String permission = android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
     != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                    {permission}, 1);

 }
```

> **now handle permisiion result**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // perform your action here
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera_permission_granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera_permission_not_granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have 
 
i have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
in the android manifest. Do i need to ask it again from the code like above?

Comment: @Tejas yes you need to ask again run time permission because **Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.**